# Saving fetch() data to array variable to use in another outside function(s)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fetch

So, I am trying to grab the data from the GET fetch that I used.

```html
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000/quotes"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    randomButton();
    createButton();
    loadQuotes();
});

const loadQuotes = function() {
    fetch(BASE_URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
            results.data.forEach(json => json.attributes.sentence)
        });
}

function addQuote(quote) {
    let ul = document.querySelector('#quote-display');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = quote;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

When I wrap a console.log around **json.attributes.sentence** or use the addQuote(json.attributes.sentence) function like so. I definitely get the out put in the console.log/in the ul/li tags. I also ran a typeof on the **json.attributes.sentence** and it shows it's outputting strings.

However, I would like to add that data to an array to access later from other methods.
I tried creating a global variable that was an empty array and push the json data attribute strings to the array but didn't work. Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

btw the JSON looks like this

```html
{
  data: [
          {
            id: "1",
            type: "quote",
              attributes: {
                sentence: "Here's looking at you, kid."
              }
          }
        ]
}
```

Comment: `results.data.forEach(json => json.attributes.sentence)` effectively does nothing - you've retrieved the data, then done nothing with it, not even saved it anywhere, how are you expecting to access it outside that `.then`?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. Would it be a "POST" method that I a missing?

Comment: well, I don't know what your API endpoint expects, and I was referring to the handling of the *result* not the request - if the request doesn't work, then ... yeah, that's a problem too, but in the end, you do nothing with the result anyway

Comment: you are right, I need to render them in some way